# PHP Sort array alphabetically, but specific items should appear first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm using the [Wordpress store locator plugin](https://wpstorelocator.co/).

I have an array with stores and I want to sort the result alphabetically, but there are two "special stores" which should be the first results when I output the array.

I already got what I want on a basic example

```
$stores = array("A", "B", "C", "D");

usort($stores, function($a, $b) {

if ($b == "C") {
  return 1;
}

});

foreach ($stores as $store) {
  echo $store;
}
```

But I don't know how to achieve this with the plugin. According to the [docs of the plugin](https://wpstorelocator.co/document/change-search-results-order/) this is how you sort the stores.

```
add_filter( 'wpsl_store_data', 'custom_result_sort' );

function custom_result_sort( $store_meta ) {

    $custom_sort = array();

    foreach ( $store_meta as $key => $row ) {
        $custom_sort[$key] = $row['store'];
    }

    array_multisort( $custom_sort, SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR, $store_meta );

    return $store_meta;
}
```

It uses `array_multisort` and I don't know if I can use usort somehow to make the two special stores appear first. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The plugin just provides a filter to hook into to sort the results, but that doesn’t mean you _must_ do it this exact way. Your `custom_result_sort` function can do whatever it likes to sort the data, it just has to return the sorted array in the end. You just need to figure out where in the data structure you got the value you want to sort by is located to begin with.

Comment: Please post the data that you need to sort. As described above, there is no need to use the code as-is, just the output needs to be in the right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with this solution. Just add prefix before the store name and then sort using `array_multisort()` with `SORT_ASC` and `SORT_STRING`:

```
function custom_result_sort( $store_meta ) {

    $custom_sort = array();

    foreach ( $store_meta as $key => $row ) {
        $store = $row['store'];
        if (($store == 'SpecialStore1') || ($store == 'SpecialStore2')) {
            $prefix = '0_';
        } else {
            $prefix = '1_';
        }
        $custom_sort[$key] = $prefix.$store;
    }

    array_multisort( $custom_sort, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $store_meta );

    return $store_meta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stores = array("A", "B", "C", "D");
asort($stores);
foreach ($stores as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```